# How to relate three tables in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to develop a p2p app in laravel.

I have three tables in my database namely users, loans, and installments.

Now, users and loans can have multiple installments and each installment will belong to a user and a loan.

So how do I define this relationship? Do I need a polymorphic relationship? If so, how do relate a user and a loan to a single installment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> each installment will belong to a user **and** a loan.

That pretty much answers the question.

If your requirement was *"each installment will belong to **either** an user **or** a loan"*, then the relationship would be polymorphic.

#### Minimal table structure

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    ... // other users fields or indexes.
});

Schema::create('loans', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    ... // other loans fields or indexes.
});

Schema::create('installments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
    $table->foreignId('loan_id')->constrained('loans');
    ... // other installments fields or indexes.
});
```

IF an Installment's `user_id` or `loan_id` can be null, add `->nullable()` before `->constrained()`. For example:

```php
Schema::create('installments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained('users');
    ...
});
```

IF you can't have more than one installment associated with the same user/loan pair, add a unique index.

```php
Schema::create('installments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
    $table->unique(['user_id', 'loan_id']);
    ...
});
```

#### Relationships to define

User model:

- `public function installments() { return $this->hasMany(Installment::class); }`
- `public function loans() { return $this->belongsToMany(Loan::class, 'installments'); }`

Loan model:

- `public function installments() { return $this->hasMany(Installment::class); }`
- `public function users() { return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'installments'); }`

Installment model:

- `public function loan() { return $this->belongsTo(Loan::class); }`
- `public function user() { return $this->belongsTo(User::class); }`

https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations

https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#updating-a-record-on-the-intermediate-table

`syncWithoutDetaching()` and `updateExistingPivot()` are particularly important methods if you have a unique constraint.

Comment: Just like you would add a column.

Comment: No, how do I do CRUD operations?

Comment: With either a hasMany or belongsToMany relationship.